# What is the diff between RegDeleteKeyValue and RegDeleteValue?

Tags: winapi

I want to know what is the different between RegDeleteKeyValue and RegDeleteValue in Win32API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RegDeleteValue() is the legacy function, it has been around for 22 years.  RegDeleteKeyValue() was an *addition*, first available on Vista.  Major version 6, you must set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to 0x600 or higher to be able to use it.  Won't work on Windows XP, Server 2003 or earlier.

Version 6 altered the behavior of several registry related functions, otherwise without a fantastic documented rationale that I've ever seen.  The changes however *look* like Microsoft tried to make them less easy to exploit by malware.  RegDeleteValue() fits, it is quite a dangerous function.  Whacking the `hKey` argument with a buffer overflow, giving it one of the predefined values like HKEY_CURRENT_USER and an attacked program can instantly destroy the user's machine.  I think, never tried it :)

So you definitely want to consider RegDeleteKeyValue().

Answer (score 4):

Both [`RegDeleteValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724851.aspx) and [`RegDeleteKeyValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724848.aspx) remove a value from the [Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724871.aspx). The difference is one of convenience: Applications and system components often structure registry data in groups of subkeys, each holding a list of values. `RegDeleteKeyValue` allows reuse of the parent key handle when deleting values from several subkeys. With `RegDeleteValue` you have to open a handle to each subkey individually.

Additional reading:

- [What is the terminology for describing the various parts of the registry?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/04/9394113.aspx)
- [Why do registry keys have a default value?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/18/7145021.aspx)